# Fast user switching: how to prevent volumes from being unmounted?

Tags: macos, login, mount, user-account, disk-volume

I have a volume mounted. If I switch to another user, this volume gets dismounted. The problem is that I want this volume to be available for every user (but putting it in their login items is not the solution I'm looking for), so: how can this behavior be prevented?
(I'm on Mountain Lion)

Comment: Are you mounting the volume manually after logging in?

Comment: Yes, that's what I do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can stop Mac OS X unmounting user disks on log-out. This behaviour is controlled with a default (preference).

In [this discussion on the Apple Support Community](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2679558?start=0&tstart=0), [Király](https://discussions.apple.com/people/Kir%C3%A1ly) shares the appropriate command to issue:

```
defaults write /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/autodiskmount AutomountDisksWithoutUserLogin -bool YES
```

This command needs to be entered into Applications > Utilities > Terminal.app. Aftwards you must **restart your Mac** for the change to take effect.

Note that the `autodiskmount` tool has been replaced by `automountd`; it is possible Mac OS X 10.8 has migrated this default to another file.

You may also find this Super User question useful, [Automount external hard drive on Mac](https://superuser.com/questions/360276/automount-external-hard-drive-on-mac).

Comment: Just a note that I tested the AutomountDisksWithoutUserLogin flag with 10.9.4 and it still works properly.